# Permission denied reading /dev/block/mmcblk0p4 as root

Tags: adb, 5.1-lollipop, file-permissions, htc-one-s

I will list my main objective first, dependencies after. If there is a better path to my goal, please show me the way....

- I want to [install Lollipop](http://www.android.gs/update-htc-one-s-to-android-5-1-1-lollipop-with-resurrection-remix-5-4-4-custom-rom/) on my HTC One S. *(Or a later version, if one is compatible with the One S, Google Play Services included.)*
- For this I need [HBOOT 2.16](https://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one-s/general/guide-how-to-install-hboot-2-16-time-t2898605)
- For this I need [S-OFF](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2155135)
- For this I need [Super cid: 11111111](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1671643)

(Phew, what a hassle!)

I am working up from the bottom of this list: the instructions for Super cid begin

```
adb shell
su
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p4 of=/sdcard/mmcblk0p4
```

This gives me a permission denied error. Here is the full contents of the shell:

```
#> adb shell
shell@ville:/ $ su
255|shell@ville:/ $ dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p4 of=/sdcard/mmcblk0p4
/dev/block/mmcblk0p4: cannot open for read: Permission denied
1|shell@ville:/ $ ls -al /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
brw------- root     root     179,   4 2017-02-28 20:35 mmcblk0p4
shell@ville:/ $
```

I find it odd that `su` seems to change the user to `255` and the failure of `dd` seems to change the user to `1`, but what do I know?

Why is this permission error happening and how do I fix it?

The phone currently runs Cyanogenmod.

Comment: Sure you got root? `$ dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p4 of=/sdcard/mmcblk0p4` suggests you've run this command as ordinary user (note the `$` at the start; for root this would have been a `#`). Hint: In developer settings, you need to enable root for ADB.